# How do mathematically I represent data binding between a set and a list?

Tags: notation

Suppose I have a set of entities e.g.

$$S = \{apple, cat, hat, fruit\}$$

and I have their corresponding similarity scores

$$ E = \{0.8, 0.1, 0.9, 1.0\} $$

How do I represent the **S** in decreasing order of their corresponding similarity scores in **E** in another list?

This is what I have done

> We are using scores in E and sorted the list R in decreasing order
> $$R = [s_i, s_{i+1}, s_{i+2}, ... , s_n] : s \varepsilon S$$ where $$\{s_i > s_{i+1} > s_{i+2} ... > s_n\} : s \varepsilon E$$

I apologize in advance if I have come up with an unintuitive solution but after trying for hours, this is what I could only think of. Is it correct and how can we represent it in a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create a mapping $f: S \to E$ such that $f(apple)=0.8,\ f(cat)=1.0, f(hat)=0.9$ and $f(fruit)=1.0$.

Then we could define our set $R$ as follows:

$$R=\{s_1,\cdots,s_{|S|} |\ f(s_i) \geq f(s_j),\ i < j \leq |S|, s_i,s_j \in S \}$$

Comment: This is soo perfect! Thank you for such a beautiful solution!

Comment: You are welcome!